# Connect PowerBi to As400

Tags: powerbi, ibm-midrange, squirrel

I tried to connect to ODBC with PowerBi using this string connection

```
Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver
(32-bit)};System=xxxxx.xxx.xxxxx;libraries=XXXXXX;naming=system;transaction
isolation=read committed;
```

Connection is done but i cannot see the right tables, i see 3 folders

> EXPLOIT, INSTAL, QGPL

With different tables inside that are not tables when I connect with squirrel client, for example.

I know there are few elements to understand. Someone has any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

I found out this three catalogs (EXPLOIT, INSTAL and QGPL) also in Squirrel, but I cannot see all others catalogs that I see in Squirrel. Could be any limited views? The user is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the default library list for your server does not include QSYS2. You can access most of the DB2 for i catalog files in QSYS2. Try this:

```
Select * from qsys2.systables;
```

That should show you all the tables your heart desires, as well as the schema (library) that the table resides in.

BTW, I don't think EXPLOIT, INSTAL, and QGPL are catalogs. They are likely libraries, well QGPL is definitely a system library supplied by IBM. The other two seem to be something provided by some 3rd party app.